# Matching Apple Pencil Input to Arbitrary Symbols

Tags: swift, ipad, apple-pencil

I'm planning on creating an app that allows you to hand-draw circuits using the apple pencil. The symbols you draw will then be recognised and converted into a nice diagram.

I've had a look through the Apple Pencil SDK docs and I can't seem to see anywhere that allows you to add arbitrary symbols to match against.

Since it seems to be able to recognise and snap simple shapes and circuit symbols (generally) aren't that much more complex, this seems like something that should be achievable.

Am I missing something, or is the best way to do this going to be converting the apple pencil canvas into an image and then attempting to match against that using a CNN or something of that ilk?

Obviously, I don't expect a full solution here, just pointing towards the correct part of the SDK or another appropriate library would be amazing.